# Hiding GroupBoxes depending on selected index of combo box

Tags: c#, groupbox

I'm trying to display / hide a 2 combo boxes depending on the chosen event type. 
What the program should do is: If exhibition is selected, the groupbox of exhibition will be visible, while having the clubbing groupbox hidden.(Vice versa if clubbing is selected)

Code:

```
namespace Promoter.Forms

public partial class eventCreate : Form
{
    public eventCreate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //import enum value to combo box
        cmbEventType.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EventType));

    }

    private void eventCreate_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (cmbEventType.Text == "Exhibition")
        {
            grpClubbing.Visible = false;

            grpExhibition.Visible = true;
            //import enum values to combo box
            cmbExhibitionVenue.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ExhibitionVenue));

        }
        else if (cmbEventType.Text == "Clubbing")
        {
            grpExhibition.Visible = false;

            grpClubbing.Visible = true;
            //import enum values to combo box
            cmbClubbingVenue.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClubbingVenue));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SelectedIndexChanged event.

```
    private void cmdEventType_SelectedIndexChanged( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
        grpClubbing.Visible=false;
        grpExibition=false;
        switch ( cb.SelectedText ) {
            case "Exhibition":
                grpExhibition.Visible = true;
                //import enum values to combo box
                cmbExhibitionVenue.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ExhibitionVenue));
                break;
            case "Clubbing":
                grpClubbing.Visible = true;
                //import enum values to combo box
                cmbClubbingVenue.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClubbingVenue));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, just had a logic missing from my mind.

Instead of

```
private void eventCreate_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I had to reason out and do it at:

```
private void cmbEventType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```